# "Support on the project" or "support with the project"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, predicate-frames

What would be the correct preposition to use?

> Thanks for your support **on/with** the project.

Answer (score 1):

Support usually takes the preposition "of" in your context. Here are two examples of ways to word this response:

> Thank you for your support of the project.

If you want to avoid using the preposition altogether, you could make it more concise by saying:

> Thank you for supporting the project.

Comment: Did the person being thanked support "the project" or the speaker? Using support of the project tends to make the thanks less personal, which may or may not be appropriate.

Comment: It's hard to say, based on the example. I think it could mean people who helped complete the project or people who contributed through donations. I agree that the first sounds less personal, but I'm not sure who of those two groups would need the more-personal thanks.

Comment: The person receiving thanks is someone who put hard work to help me see the project through. I'm implying he has worked on the project thus supporting it.